# Efficient way to read index file in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

Dictionaries usually has an index and a data file. I'm writing a dictionary application as a hobby project. I'm confused about how to read the offset file in .NET. The index file is of 4-5 MB size. What is the most efficient way to fetch the offset/length value of a word.

EDIT:
I need to know only how to read offset file if I have a word to search. ie  how to search the index file for a word so that I can get the subsequent 8 bytes

Comment: How are the words stored in the dictionary?

Comment: words are stored as stream of ASCII characters which I can read if I have the offset and start. I need to know how to search the index file for a word so that I can get the subsequent 8 bytes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4-5 megabytes for the index?  That's nothing.  Read the entire thing into a byte array and with it as a MemoryStream or more appropriately, parse the entire contents into appropriate data structures for quick searching (has, b-tree, etc).

Comment: i cant parse it unless I know the search key. What to do? I have to search the entire 5MB data everytime I need to get a word. then take the offset and length from subsequent bytes and fetch from the actual data file? But how to handle search keys that match substrings of a word in the index file?

Comment: Parse the dictionary, not the index.  The dictionary is entirely the right size to read into an array/memorystream.  Once you've parsed the dictionary you can put it into a more palatable form.  Note that unless the dictionary format or contents change, this is something you do precisely once.

Answer (score 3):

`Stream.Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)` will be usefull to get to the offset.

Answer (score 0):

System.IO.BinaryReader has a ReadUInt32 method that reads an unsigned int. It also has different methods for reading binary files.